# How to fix value error when doing python slicing and indexing?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, statistics

There is a csv file with 463916 rows. 
The first column is the gender column.
1 is male, 2 is female.
The second column is age.
It has 0 to 85.
The third column is education level, but we don't need that field in this homework.

I want result like this.

male    female

under10  0.5     0.5

s10(10's) 0.4     0.6

s20(20's) 0.5     0.5

s30(20's) 0.5     0.5

s40(20's) 0.5     0.5

s50(20's) 0.5     0.5

over60   0.6     0.4

I found the population for each age group, but there was an error in the function to obtain the sex ratio. And I don't know how can I deal with over60!
But I can't use pandas because I haven't learn that...
I'm a beginner of python. Please help me!!

data is below

```
array([[ 1,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  1],
       ...,
       [ 2, 85,  6],
       [ 2, 85,  7],
       [ 2, 85,  7]], dtype=int64)


import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("population.csv", delimiter = ",", dtype = 'int64')

under10=s10=s20=s30=s40=s50=over60=0

def sex(age, total):
    male=female=0
    while(data[:,1]<age):
        if(data[:,0]==1):
            male+=1    
        else:
            break
    female=total-male
    print(male/total,female/total)

for i in data[:,1]:
    if (i<10):
        under10 += 1
    elif (i<20):
        s10 +=1
    elif (i<30):
        s20 +=1
    elif (i<40): 
        s30 +=1
    elif (i<50):
        s40 +=1
    elif (i<60):
        s50 +=1
    else:
        over60 +=1
sex(10, under10)
sex(20, s10)
sex(30, s20)
sex(40, s30)
sex(50, s40)
sex(60, s50)
sex(?)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-53c9486669b3> in <module>
     31     else:
     32         over60 +=1
---> 33 sex(10, under10)

<ipython-input-51-53c9486669b3> in sex(age, total)
      6 def sex(age, total):
      7     male=female=0
----> 8     while(data[:,1]<age):
      9         if(data[:,0]==1):
     10             male+=1

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is         ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: data[:,1] gives you an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `data[:,1]` is giving you the whole column. That is fine but then your while loop should rather iterate over the values.

```
for row in data:
    # row is array([1, 0, 1])
    if row[1] < age:
        # row[1] is 0
        if row[0] == 1:
           # row[1] is 0
           male += 1
```